# How to programmatically access the apps language in iOS 13?

Tags: ios, ios13

[Starting from iOS 13](https://web.archive.org/web/20200815085807/https://www.apple.com/ios/ios-13/features/) Apple allows to:

> Language selection per app
>
> Use third‑party apps in a different language from your system
> language.

As I can see in the Settings app on the settings page of my app there is a new "Prefered Language" entry revealing a selection of the localized languages of my app.

Example from Facebook:

[image: iOS App Facebook Settings]

[Image source](https://www.igeeksblog.com/how-to-change-language-of-specific-apps-on-iphone-ipad/)

---

Can I programmatically access the value of the selected language?

If so with which key?

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"key???"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try the below code to get the application preferred language.

```
let appLang = Locale.preferredLanguages[0]
```

Answer (score 4):

I usually add this little extension:

```
public extension Locale {
    /// Returns the prefered locale used in the app, if none is found, returns `Locale.current`
    static var appCurrent : Locale {
        if let prefered = Bundle.main.preferredLocalizations.first {
            return Locale(identifier: prefered)
        }
        else {
            return current
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use `Locale.appCurrent` to retrieve it.

> **NOTE**: I use `Bundle.preferedLocalizations` instead of `Locale.preferedLocale` because it returns the real app language. For instance, if your phone is in French and your app is only localized in English, the `Bundle.preferedLocalizations` will return `en`, because this is the `Locale` your app runs in. The `Locale.preferedLocale` will return `French` but all other localizations will be in English, because your app runs in English on a French device.

**EDIT**: Here is the Objective-C version.

```
@interface NSLocale(AppCurrent)

+ (NSLocale *) appCurrent;

@end

@implementation NSLocale(AppCurrent)

+ (NSLocale *) appCurrent {
    NSString * prefered = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] preferredLocalizations] firstObject];
    if (prefered != nil) {
        return [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:prefered];
    }
    else {
        return [NSLocale currentLocale];
    }
}

@end
```

Then, call it this way: `[NSLocale appCurrent]`

Comment: Great answer! This technical note displays the way you could use it to match to your app's localized languages: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2418/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to reach "Locale.current.languageCode"

Answer (score 0):

To detect the device language you can use this:

```
let locale = Locale.current.languageCode
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the **Device language**:

```
let locale = NSLocale.current.languageCode
```

To get the **App language**:

```
let appLang = Locale.preferredLanguages[0]
```